# Options for displaying a map in a PhoneGap application for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am in the process of developing a PhoneGap application for Android and iOS.  The application will feature a map including several points of interest.

I am aware of the following methods for displaying a map within a phonegap application:

1. Make use of the Google Maps JavaScript API V3.
2. Create a native Android app and embed a CordovaWebView, as suggested in the following blog: [(Link)](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/931)
3. Make use of a google maps plugin such as GMPlugin, as illustrated in the following git repo: [(Link)](https://github.com/imhotep/MapsPluginExample)

Are there any other options that I have missed? What would be the benefits and complications with the above listed options?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So does this mean there isn't a good way to use Google maps with PhoneGap on Android?